(Natbib, Vancouver) How to remove et al after 6th author and show all authors in the bibliography list
The issue:
I'm having an issue with the bibliography once converted to PDF don't show 7th author name and beyond. The authornames that are not shown are replace by "et al." I looked around on StackExchange, but found lot's solutions involving editing *.bst files which I don't currently use and as I understand is not relevant in my case.
The result looks like this:

I want to show all author names. Does anybody know how to achieve this?
Behind the stage and elsewhere
The text with MWE cite commands:
Many of the galaxy clusters in the observable universe have shown remarkable variations in their star formation rates \cite{Thompson2020GalaxyClusterDynamics, Johnson2021DarkMatterMapping, Wilson2019BlackHoleActivityInGalaxies, Patel2023StarFormationRates, Gomez2020GravitationalLensingEffects, Brown2022ExoplanetDiscoveryMethods}.

I'm using natbib like this and have the following documentclass:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

A bibliography MWE list is like this:
@article{Thompson2020GalaxyClusterDynamics,
  author = {Thompson, R. A. and Lee, S. J. and Patel, M. K. and Kim, H. S. and Garcia, L. M. and Zhang, Y. F. and Singh, A. P. and Martinez, J. R. and O'Reilly, M. C. and Russo, N. E.},
  title = {Exploring the Dynamics of Galaxy Clusters},
  journal = {Journal of Astrophysical Dynamics},
  volume = {12},
  number = {3},
  pages = {345-367},
  year = {2020},
  month = {05},
  issn = {2041-8205},
  doi = {10.1080/jad.2020.12.345}
}


@article{Johnson2021DarkMatterMapping,
author = {Johnson, M. and Davies, L. and Smith, K. and Turner, A. and Rodriguez, F. and Nguyen, H. and Li, W. and Shah, P. and Martinez, D. and Garcia, S. and O'Neill, J.},
year = {2021},
title = {Mapping Dark Matter in Distant Galaxy Clusters},
journal = {Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics},
volume = {15},
pages = {25-40},
doi = {10.1015/jcap.2021.15.25}
}

I'm using this environment/these settings on Overleaf.com:


I found out that BST-files are relevant when using Natbib.
The solution for 2020 mentioned by Mico here works (doing what Mico suggest in reverse or adding a max number of authors that is very large e.g 100 {in the BST-code that Mico uses/show)}:
BibTeX: How to reduce long author lists to "Firstauthor et al."?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
